# HTML5 Canvas: Why is my circle not drawn?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Below is a sketch of my code. I want to draw a circle on top of an image. The image is shown, but the circle isn't.

```
ctx=can.getContext('2d');
backpic=document.getElementById('canpic');
ctx.drawImage(backpic,0,0);
pos=[100,100];
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.arc(pos[0],pos[1],40,0,2 * Math.PI,false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you call ctx.restore() instead of ctx.Save() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circle works on fiddle.

```
can = document.getElementById("can");
ctx=can.getContext('2d');
pos=[100,100];
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.arc(pos[0],pos[1],40,0,2 * Math.PI,false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8TNdZ/

Comment: I now see that the bug was not in my code. Thanks for pointing it out.